# Vue.js - redirect to desktop site if user enters vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to redirect user to another page `(with different URL)` if user enters my vue site on device different than mobile. How can I do it the right way to minimize page loading time, or even prevent page loading and instantly redirect him to my desktop website?

My `vue.js` version is `2.1.10`and if it helps in any way vue-router: `2.2.0`

Thanks for help

Comment: `if(! /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )`

Comment: It doesn't help mate. Where do I put code in vue.js framework to make it redirect fast and omit web page loading?

Comment: "and omit web page loading" you cannot do that with a frontend framework.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file?